# OSGi bundle repository with plain Maven JARs

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf, eclipse-virgo, pax

I am working on to reach a solution to deploy a web application as a bundle to Virgo 3.0.1.RELEASE. My scenario is:

- I use [Maven Bundle Plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) to generate the manifest.
- I exclude all the JAR dependencies using [Maven WAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html).
- I need to command Virgo to host the **plain** Maven JAR artifacts in the local repository. As an instance [Apache Karaf along with PAX](http://davidvaleri.wordpress.com/2010/08/13/combining-karaf-features-pax-url-and-maven-to-deploy-a-plain-jar-as-an-osgi-bundle/) can provide plain JAR files as OSGi bundles.

So,

1. Any ideas on how to configure Virgo for to host Maven repository **plain** JARs?
2. Generally, in your experience, what is the best solution to use a ready Maven repository and host it as an OBR?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found so far is actually using [Wrap Deployer](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/users-guide/deployer.html) on Apache Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

Basically stick with Karaf, since it provides all you need :)
With Karaf and the features you don't really need a OBR, since the features service does a pretty good job of resolving already deployed bundles and won't install those again. You need to add the OBR flag to your features file though.